# Import multiple files with TK inter module

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have developed an algorithm to export an vcf file to excel.
Now I want to make a user interface with an option to import multiple vcf files into 1 entry with a browse button.

```
class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Vcf to excel converter")
        self.geometry("300x200")
        self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.entry=Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.button = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.load_file, width=10)
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=6, sticky=E)

        self.button1= Button(self, text="Convert", width=10)
        self.button1.grid(row=100, column=3, sticky=E)
    def load_file(self):
        fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Vcards", "*.vcf"),
                                            ))
        if fname:
            try:
                print("""here it comes: self.settings["template"].set(fname)""")
            except:                     # <- naked except is a bad idea
                showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % fname)
            return

MyFrame().mainloop()
```

Above you see the algorithm for 1 vcf file.
The idea is to select in this brwoser multiple files in the same directory into one entry and export it this entry to a list like:

[["D:\Documents\1.vcf"],[["D:\Documents\2.vcf"],["D:\Documents\3.vcf"]...]

So i want the full directory in this list to use it for my function.
Does someone now how I can do this with Tkinter?

Kind regards,

Glenn

Answer (score 0):

Add an `s` to `askopenfilename` if you want to select multiple files:

```
fnames = askopenfilenames()

print(fnames.split())
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I can't get them into a list because I constantly get a "u" before my direction and i don't now where it comes from like:[u'D:/Documents/1', u' D:/Documents/2', u' D:/Documents/3', u' D:/Documents/4', u'']

Comment: That means it's a unicode string, it doesn't have any affect on making the returned value a list. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings